# Use Slack api (Bolt for JavaScript) to upload a streamed response

Tags: file, stream, upload, slack, bolt

I'm trying to build an application that creates a file on a server and then streams the content of that file to the client.

I have code on the client side that looks something like this:

```
app.event('app_home_opened', async ({ event, client, context }) => {
  try {
    const response: AxiosResponse<fs.ReadStream> = await axios({
      method: 'post',
      url: `${process.env.SOME_URL}/create`,
      data: {},
      headers: {},
      responseType: 'stream',
    });

    app.client.files.upload({
      file: response.data,
      channels: event.channel,
    });

  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e);
  }
});
```

and on the server:

```
router.post(
  '/create',
  async (
    req: Request<any, any, any>,
    res: Response<Stream>,
    next: NextFunction
  ) => {
    try {
      const stream = fs.createReadStream('path/to/some/file.csv');

      stream
        .on('data', function (chunk: any) {
          console.log(chunk);
        })
        .on('end', function () {
          stream.pipe(res);
          next();
        })

        .on('close', function (err: any) {
          console.log('Stream has been Closed');
        });
    } catch (e) {
      next(e);
    }
  }

);
```

The post request returns this error:

```
(node:70966) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: An API error occurred: no_file_data
```

The Typescript compiles fine, so I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The upload method of Slack client is to upload the file, but seems you already upload the file using the path `/create`. I guess you want to have the file saved in your server and Slack storage.

In that case, you need to pass to the `client.upload` the file stream, so your async call should return it or the file path;

This could be a possible implementation:

```
try{
  const response = await post.create('/create', params);
  if(response.data.filePath)
  {
    const stream = fs.createReadStream(response.data.filePath);
    app.client.files.upload({
      file: stream,
      channels: event.channel,
    });
  }
}catch(error){
  console.error(error);
}
```